# Как составить запрос в MySQL?

Tags: запрос, mysql

Всем привет.
Есть таблица с такой структурой

```
cat_id | entry_id
```

Нужно выбрать только те `entry_id`, у которых есть нужная `cat_id` и больше никаких записей в этой таблице нет. Т.е. один `entry_id` может иметь несколько записей с разными `cat_id`.
А нужно выбрать только `entry_id` с `cat_id`, которая один раз только встречается у этой записи.

Чтобы было еще понятнее расскажу суть. Есть дерево категорий разных уровней.
И если запись относится к подкатегории какой-то, то она понятное относится и к родительской категории. Есть записи, которые только к родительской категории относятся.
И вот находясь на сайте в родительской категории, нужно выбрать записи, которые только в родительской и не имеют подкатегорий у себя никаких.

Надеюсь, понятно все объяснил)

Comment: select * from table where cat_id = 'foo'

Comment: and (select count(*) from table where cat_id = 'foo') = 1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запрос:

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM table_name
GROUP BY entry_id
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
```

выберет все `entry_id` которые связаны только с одной категорией `cat_id`.

Comment: Выбирает все равно все записи

Comment: Если нужно по определенной категории, вставь после строки с `FROM`:

    WHERE cat_id=12345678

Comment: так и есть:
SELECT entry_id FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id = ".$city_id." GROUP BY entry_id HAVING COUNT(*)=1

Comment: Если выборка ограничивается через `WHERE cat_id=`, нужно использовать подзапрос.

    SELECT t1.entry_id
    FROM table_name t1
    WHERE
        (t1.cat_id = 123) AND
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM table_name t2
            WHERE t2.entry_id=t1.entry_id
        ) = 1

Comment: Теперь все круто! Спасибо
Все путаюсь я с подзапросами